# Is it possible to check parameter datatype in the function without getting compile time error while calling that function in c#?

Tags: c#, validation, types

Is it possible to check parameter datatype in the function without getting compile time error while calling that function in c#?
I do not want to get compile time error while passing the wrong value to the function in c# like javascript.

Following is my sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static int containsThatItem(char[] arr1, char[] arr2)
    {
        Dictionary<char, bool> map = new Dictionary<char, bool>();

        foreach (var e in arr1)
        {
            map.Add(e, true);
        }

        foreach (var e in arr2)
        {
            if (!map.ContainsKey(e))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (map[e])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item Found!");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        char[] arr2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

        //Here I'm getting compile time error
        containsThatItem(arr1, arr2);   //All I want is to overcome this compile time error by adding validation of datatype inside the containsThatItem method.

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing an `int[]` as a parameter, but the expected type is `char[]`. You need to change your numbers to chars and change the array type (0 => '0', `int[]` => `char[]`).

Comment: Well, you could use objects but that's a terrible idea. Plus, you'd still have to adapt your code anyway. The right answer is: use the appropriate types, to begin with. If you get the values/arrays from somewhere else, you may cast them to the appropriate type. Read: [Casting and type conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

Comment: Also, if you want to add validation of datatype inside the containsThatItem method, then you have to write generic method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either *object* or *dynamic* parameter types.

To perform type checks you can use the [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) or [typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) operators.

Brief summary of *is* operator from MSDN

> Use the is operator to check if the type can be converted by a reference conversion, a boxing conversion, or an unboxing conversion.

Brief summary of *typeof* operator from MSDN

> Use the typeof operator to check if the runtime type of the expression result exactly matches a given type.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass it as an `object`.

And you can check the Data Type using `GetType` function.

Here is a code representing my solution, it may contain errors but you should be able to fix it according to your logic, I'm just illustrating the idea of solution.

```
static int containsThatItem(object arr1, object arr2)
        {
            if (arr1.GetType() == typeof(int[]) && arr2.GetType() == typeof(char[]))
            {
                int[] Converted_arr1 = (int[]) arr1;
                char[] Converted_arr2 = (char[]) arr2;

                Dictionary<char, bool> map = new Dictionary<char, bool>();

                foreach (var e in Converted_arr1)
                {
                    map.Add(e, true);
                }

                foreach (var e in Converted_arr2)
                {
                    if (!map.ContainsKey(e))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (map[e])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Item Found!");
                    }
                }

            }

            return 0;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
            char[] arr2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };

            //Here I'm getting compile time error
            containsThatItem(arr1, arr2);   //All I want is to overcome this compile time error by adding validation of datatype inside the containsThatItem method.

        }
```